# Unable to display 3d pdf image on web page

Tags: html, pdf

I  want to display a 3d pdf image on my web page but it not display  This is my code

```
<object data="2010NissanAltima.pdf"  type="application/pdf" width="630" height="450"></object>
```

Comment: I want to show a 3d PDF on my web page It show only pdf file 3d image is missing, is their any special code for 3d image.

Answer (score 0):

PDF 3D annotations are not widely supported by PDF readers, so you will have to make sure that your file is been rendered with Adobe Acrobat Reader instead of one of the internal PDF reader alternatives provided by some web-browsers like Chrome and Firefox.

See this post about about to change these settings in Chrome for example:
https://superuser.com/questions/735751/chrome-open-pdfs-in-adobe-not-in-the-browser